# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'reflectionId' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a deeply nested object and I'm trying to get a specific value from it. On my development and production environment, the function returns the error above (TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'reflectionId' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.) However, I am unable to debug this, and when I put in the exact same object and function into a code sandbox, **it works fine**.

I have recreated my object and code in a codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-bird-rknxrr?file=/src/index.js:28281-28461
(check the console to see the working output)

```
const discordLink = CHARACTER_MAP
  .flatMap((character) => character.chapters)
  .find(({ reflectionId }) => reflectionId === reflectionNum).discordLink;
```

What could the problem be? The flatMap returns a properly formatted object (checked that). `reflectionId` is the property name I am looking for, and it seems correctly defined in both my live code and the sandbox. Based on how .find() is described in [the Mozilla docs] [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) it seems like I'm using the "Using arrow function and destructuring" method properly too. It's most puzzling that it works in codesandbox but not in live.

[image: Error message]

Comment: how do you get those CHARACTER_MAP array? It could be a promise related issue

Comment: Hmm.. but it's not a async/promise object. It's a static JSON object that I pass in from another file. I've recreated the exact CHARACTER_MAP array in the code sandbox.

Comment: To add some more context - I also reference the same CHARACTER_MAP in other parts of the code and it works fine. For reference, this function works with no issues, just a few lines above the problematic one:
`const persona = CHARACTER_MAP.find((character) => character.characterId === characterId);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
const discordLink = CHARACTER_MAP
  .flatMap((character) => character.chapters)
  .find((reflection) => reflection.reflectionId === reflectionNum).discordLink
```

Comment: There's a typo in your code - it should be `find((reflectionId` 
I tried this in the code sandbox and it didn't work for me. Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'discordLink')

Did it work for you in the code sandbox?

Comment: Also, based on the mozilla docs for find, arrow fn + destructuring is allowed.
`const result = inventory.find( ({ name }) => name === 'cherries' );` (from the docs)